# mysql/php undefined variable isset not working

Tags: php, mysql

I keep receiving this error "undefined variable :cbanned" and i have searched all over your forums and there is no solution relating to my problem can someone please help. and i have tried the keyword isset and it has failed just to prove that this is a valid case.

```
<?php
    echo $sgt.$tt.$fbt.$rdt;
?>
<li class="hidden-xs">
    <a href="#" class="right-bar-toggle waves-effect"><?php if($cbanned==0) {echo'<i class="fa fa-comments"></i></a>';}else{echo'<i class="fa fa-microphone-slash"></i>';} ?>
</li>
```

Comment: Where do you define `$cbanned`?  How did you try to use `isset`?  How does MySQL play into this question?

Comment: `if (isset($cbanned) && $cbanned==0)` -- but then it won't do anything, because as the compiler is telling you: *It's not defined or set*